# Laravel and Json, don't show the index of the array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I'm using Laravel to return a JSON object and I can't find a way to delete the index of my array.

My code :

```
<?php

class PlayerController extends BaseController {

public function checkupdate()
{   

    $datapack = DB::table('datapack')->first();        

    return Response::json(array(['datapack'=>$datapack],'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),200);

}
}
```

which give me :

```
{
   "0":{
      "datapack":{
         "id":"FD524D0F-5732-44B7-AC46",
         "timeUpdated":1401184091
      }
   },
   "time":"2014-10-06 15:58:20"
}
```

and I want something like this :

```
{          
      "datapack":{
         "id":"FD524D0F-5732-44B7-AC46",
         "timeUpdated":1401184091          
   },
   "time":"2014-10-06 15:58:20"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
return Response::json(array(['datapack'=>$datapack],'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),200);
```

into:

```
return Response::json(array('datapack'=>$datapack,'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),200);
```

You put the `datapack` in its own sub-array with the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a level of array nesting in there you don't need.

Instead of

```
Response::json(array(['datapack'=>$datapack],'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),200);
```

Try

```
Response::json(array('datapack'=>$datapack,'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),200);
```